# Prove that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if it is an eigenbalor of $[T]_\beta$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, and let $\beta$ be a basis for $V$. Then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if it is an eigenvalue of $[T]_\beta$.

It occurs to me to use a result, which says: $det(T-\lambda l_v)=det([T]_\beta-\lambda I)$.
It relates the eigenvalue $\lambda$ to $T$ and $[T]_\beta$.

Comment: "eigenbalor"?${}$

Comment: Just use the definition: if $T$ is a linear operator on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with ordered basis $\beta$. We define the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)$ of $T$ to be the characteristic polynomial of $[T]_{\beta}$, i.e., $$p(\lambda)=\det([T]_{\beta}-\lambda I_{n}).$$